# Numpy returns .00...002

Tags: python, numpy

Sorry if this post is a dupli,I couldn't find an answer... I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np

V = np.array([[6, 10, 0],
              [2, 5, 0],
              [0, 0, 0]])

subarr = np.array([[arr[0][0], arr[0][1]], [arr[1][0], arr[1][1]]])
det = np.linalg.det(subarr)
cross = np.cross(arr[0], arr[1])

print(f"Det: {det}")
print(f"Cross: {cross}")
```

I would expect that the `det` would return 10.0 and the `cross` returns in this case `[0, 0, 10]`, the last number being equal to the `det`. For some reason, python returns

```
Det: 10.000000000000002
Cross: [ 0  0 10]
```

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: Look for floating point accuracy

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: keyword: [floating point precision](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is [floating point inaccuracies.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

And in case you're wondering how you end up with floats when finding the determinant of a matrix made up of integers (where the usual calculation method is just `6*5 - 2*10 = 10`), `np.linalg.det` uses [LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) to find the determinant.  This isn't very efficient for 2x2 matrices, but is much more efficient when you have bigger matrices.

For your 2x2, you get:

```
scipy.linalg.lu(A, 1)
Out: 
(array([[  1.        ,  0.        ],
        [  0.33333333,  1.        ]]), 
 array([[  6.        ,  10.        ],
        [  0.        ,   1.66666667]]))
```

The determinant is just the product of the diagonals from this, which ends up being `6. * 1.66666667`, which resolves to `10.00000002` due to floating point errors.